# How to justify spacing without using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm not using flexbox because of less browser support.
Now I have 6 li in a wrapper. Wrapper is of 900px and each li is of 400px. How am I able to justify spacing between them? so two elements are in one line and each having margins of 25px at both left and right side. I also have to make them responsive so I don't want to just hard code them. refer to image please.

[image: 'image']

Comment: Your css and html please.

Comment: Why don't you do inline-block on the elements & % width them.

Comment: If you have the width of the li's as 400px and give left and right margin of 50px, you cannot have 2 li's side by side, coz the other li (which you want to place in the same line ) would also carry the same dimenetsions - ie 500px, which makes your row (of 2 li's) of 1000px, which is more than your container (900px).

Comment: I meant 25 25 margin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
ul {
  max-width: 900px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
li {
  height: 40px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 40%;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
  margin: 25px 5%;
  margin: calc(25px);
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

It's rather simple, really, if you don't mind older browsers getting a slightly inferior experience (browsers that lack support for `calc` will see the cells at a different width, because the margin and cells both have to add up to `50%`, so they will fall back on `margin: 25px 5%`, while browsers that do support it will use `calc(50% - 50px)`, which is the entire margin).

Note that on smaller sizes, the `margin` is maintained but the blocks change size until they reach their max-width. Also note that the font-size has to be reset inside the `li`, as it is set to `0` in the `ul` to take away any spacing between `inline-block`s. This is, however, not necessary since the blocks would always fill the space and the container centers itself, so you might want to leave `font-size` alone and `float` your `li`s to the left, adding the following line to your css:

```
ul:after { width: 100%; content: ''; clear: both; }
```

to make sure your `ul` takes up the appropriate amount of space as `float`-ed elements do not do that for you.

Comment: Pretty much every browser that supports calc also supports flexbox http://caniuse.com/#search=calc http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @JosephYoung that's true, but this works regardless of that and has an easy fallback for browsers that don't. (I personally do not know why anyone would want support for IE8 - also, note that Flexbox has more issues on the IE side than the calc implementation)

Comment: This is much less "broken" on browsers that don't support calc than flexbox would be on browsers that don't support flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution justify spacing list blocks without using flexbox.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.main-wrap {
  postion: relative;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.item-wrap {
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.list-item {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.list-item:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <ul class="item-wrap">
  
    <li class="list-item">  
      block1
    </li>  
    <li class="list-item">  
      block2
    </li>
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
   
    <li class="list-item">  
      block3
    </li>  
    <li class="list-item">  
      block4
    </li>
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
     <li class="list-item">  
      block5
     </li>  
     <li class="list-item">  
      block6
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```